# unlink fails with space in filename

Tags: php, html

I am trying to unlink files which have their checkbox ticked, but I am getting this error with filenames having spaces like "Untitled Document" (it reads up to 'Untitled'):

```
Warning: unlink(../pdf_files/Untitled) [function.unlink]: No such file
or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs
```

I am passing the values using:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="file[]" value = ' . $num . ' />';
```

It appears that the array `file[]` stores the first word of a filename containing spaces. How can I fix this please?

Comment: What is `$num` in this situation? Is that the actual filename, rather than a number? If so, that won't work, since you can't have spaces in form element names. It would be better to have an integer here representing a data row in a database, perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap the `value` attribute in quotes.  Otherwise it will show like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="file[]" value=Untitled Document />
```

So the browser will only see `Untitled` as the `value` and then have a stray `Document` attribute which does nothing.  Try the following:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="file[]" value="' . $num . '" />';
```

Comment: is using value={$num} the same with value='".$num."'?

Comment: `value="{$num}"` would work...you still need the quotes though to encapsulate the entire `value`

Comment: It works finally, thanks man a simple solution but not taught of